# How badly will my future job prospects be affected after having my PhD graduation date extended by more than 3 years (due to health)?

Tags: publications, career-path, postdocs, job-search

Do I still have the possibility of a career in Academia? Can publishing merit (Qualitative and Quantitative) save me?

Comment: The date your thesis is accepted by your examiners is far more important than your graduation date.

Comment: @user2768 True but it seems relatively unlikely that the asker submitted their thesis, was examined and then fell so ill for three years that they couldn't graduate until they recovered. It seems much more likely that the health problems delayed submission rather than just graduation. Asker, please clarify the situation. (Having said that, it probably doesn't make much difference. "I had serious health problems" is a pretty good reason for taking a long time to complete a PhD.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Mmmm... the title doesn't fit on my screen, so I only see "How badly will my future job prospects be affected after having my PhD graduation date extended (due to health)?" The three year part was missing. Terrible design by Stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

It will probably have very little effect. Most jobs / grants / fellowships / etc that are time-limited for early career researchers,

1. Are based on time since submission or graduation, and pay no
   attention to when you started;
2. Allow you to argue for longer if
   there has been documented sickness (as well as maternity, and some
   other things)

The time taken might raise eyebrows on a CV, and if you are worried about not getting as far as interviews because of it you could consider mentioning in covering letters, but "I took longer because I was ill. Now I'm better" is a perfectly reasonable explanation that no sensible person will hold against you.
(if you can't say "Now I'm better", that may unfortunately be a different matter)

Comment: I am very gratefull for all your responses and comments. Thank you, very much all of you! Meanwhile, Mr. Richerby had added the inputs very correctly, I indeed missed the timeline as per the schedule year (according to the university) for submitting the thesis and so the graduation date.  But the point that disturbs largely is if I still have the possibility of a career in Academia? Or, if  publishing merit (Qualitative and Quantitative) can save me?